# Expo, Firebase, Login with google

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

in my React Native Expo application, I want to authenticate the user with google account. so I followed the [Expo Google](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google.html#using-it-inside-of-the-expo-app)for a normal sign in with google first, Which was working, then using the `idToken` and `accessToken` to authenticate with firebase.

```
  signInWithGoogleAsync = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Google.logInAsync({androidClientId: ***, iosClientId: ***, scopes: ["profile", "email"] });

      if (result.type === "success") { // I get result object
        const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential( result.idToken, result.accessToken);
        /* credential is and xf {} object */
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then(user => {console.log( user);})
          .catch(error => {console.log(error);});
        return result.accessToken;
      }
      return { cancelled: true };
    } catch (e) {
      return { error: true };
    }
  };
```

but I get the following error:

```
[Error: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"Invalid Idp Response: the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application. Its audience (OAuth 2.0 client ID) is 268165840544-097g31a3qhd0mm.apps.googleusercontent.com, which is not authorized to be used in the project with project_number: 747269174."}],"code":400,"message":"Invalid Idp Response: the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application. Its audience (OAuth 2.0 client ID) is 26816581eun236bp9vdb7b6r.apps.googleusercontent.com, which is not authorized to be used in the project with project_number: 747269174."}}]
```

Comment: The Google OAuth project does not match the Firebase project you are using. This is likely why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Add url in error message => eg. your case = `268165840544-097g31a3qhd0mm.apps.googleusercontent.com`

under

Authentication > Sign-in Method > Google

`Whitelist client IDs from external projects (optional)` on Firebase