# Link Expo/Google login to firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am attempting to use Expo's Google sign in functionality & link that authorization to my firebase auth. I am having trouble understanding how to transfer the data from the auth token received from/used by the Expo/google service to my firebase auth (i.e. create a firebase identifier, UID). I have been following the docs regarding [linking auths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) and the Expo docs for [Google sign in](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v26.0.0/sdk/google), which is where I obtained the code below. I have also looked over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228826/expo-firebase-login-with-google?rq=1) on stackoverflow but there is no accepted answer.

The two main points of confusion for me are:

1. Expo's google login and firebase's auth use similar but different ways of authenticating a user. Expo uses `Expo.Google.logInAsync()`, and a `token` while firebase uses `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()`, `auth.currentUser.linkWithRedirect(provider)`, and a `credential`.
2. If a user logs in with the Expo/Google method included below, firebase has **no record** of that user in its database, no UID, no identifier.

How would one go about ensuring that if a user logged in with the method below, a user would be created in firebase auth? like when one uses `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`

```
async logInWithGoogleAsync() {
    try {
        const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
            iosClientId: 'XXX',
            scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
        });

        if(result.type === 'success') {

            //LINK ACCOUNTS HERE?  
            //Use result.accessToken somehow? 

            return;
        }
        else {
            return {cancelled: true};
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        return {error: true};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My approach to this was pretty much what the document says, but I did have to connect quite a few dots it's not all in one place - I can help address you confusions (I had them too)

Addressing your first point - Essentially by using

> const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({

What you're doing is getting a users google details (which Expo is taking care of with the logInAsync call being made).

My approach to linking this with firebase is to use the expo provided details to create a firebase google sign in credential, then use this credential to signin. Firebase provides access to GoogleAuthProvider

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider

Expo's returned details (in your case "result") gives you access to idToken & accessToken, so , by using:

> const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);

you can create a firebase google credential, then you can leverage

> firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)

firebase will register this as a google credential and sign the user up / log them in using their google details. (Changing the AuthState)

To you second point - 
Firebase allows you to set a listener called onAuthStateChanged()

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

When you use signInWithCredential the AuthState changes and the callback is triggered - it is at this point where you should trigger a call to your firebase database - capturing all the users detailed (accessed through google sign in) and commit them into firebase database. I set this callback up in componentDidMount() so that as the user is signing up - when they press submit I'm consistently listening for authStateChanges.